# Does the List subList() method prevent garbage collection of the rest of the list?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm curious to find out how the latest JVMs would handle garbage collecting memory reserved by the following method.

```
public List<Player> getHallOfFame() {
  ArrayList<Player> listToSort = new ArrayList<Player>(map.values());
  Collections.sort(listToSort, comparator);

  return listToSort.subList(0, 5);
}
```

At worst I can imagine the JVM keeping the entire contents of `listToSort` in memory as long as there remain references to the sublist. Does anyone know if that is actually the case? I'm particularly interested in links that can prove this one way or the other for specific JVMs.

Comment: I would think that .subList returns a new List, and listToSort will go out of scope, so it would get garbage collected.

Comment: @Paul: The documentation states otherwise.

Comment: Yes, the key here is it's backed by the original list so any change in the original list is reflected in the sublist.

Comment: See also the implementation in openJDK. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractList.java.html

Comment: Well, @Jon, I always say, when you're going to make an uninformed guess, you (meaning I) should do it in a comment instead of an answer. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, `subList` is only a "view" onto the existing list. All the data is really in the original list. From the documentation:

> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

So yes, returning a sub-list will keep the original list from being garbage collected.

If you don't want that effect, you basically need to make a copy of the relevant sublist. For example:

```
return new ArrayList<Player>(listToSort.subList(0, 5));
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. The only reason I thought things might be different is that static analysis might demonstrate that the original list could no longer be changed.

Comment: @Caoilte: Things like reflection make such analysis very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

`subList` creates a new instance of `AbstractList.SubList`, which keeps a reference to original list. So if you keep the variable returned by `getHallOfFame`, it will prevent the gc to clean `listToSort`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right. Since the sublist is backed by the original list. From the java docs:

> Returns a view of the portion of this
>   list between the specified fromIndex,
>   inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If
>   fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the
>   returned list is empty.) The returned
>   list is backed by this list, so
>   non-structural changes in the returned
>   list are reflected in this list, and
>   vice-versa. The returned list supports
>   all of the optional list operations
>   supported by this list.